# JavaFX create a new image from an existing one

Tags: java, image, javafx, scale

In JavaFX u can create a new Image from a string(path), how would i go about creating a new Image from an existing javafx.scene.image.image?

as following:

```
Image image2 = new Image("my/res/flower.png", 100, 150, false, false);
```

But instead of the path an actual image object.

I want to change the size of the image.

Comment: Do you need a new `Image`? Presumably you are going to display this in an [`ImageView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html): why not just create multiple `ImageView`s from the same image?

Comment: I want to draw that scaled image onto a canvas.

Comment: So just use the [`drawImage(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#drawImage-javafx.scene.image.Image-double-double-double-double-double-double-double-double-) method that allows you to draw a scaled version. Again, there is no need to create a new image.

Comment: I don't think there is a direct way to do it other than copy pixel by pixel, if you ultimately want to change the size you can set the image to an new imageview and change the size

Comment: Ive deleted my last comment, it was a mistake on my part, scaling images via drawimage does indeed apply antialiasing, which i do not want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is typically no need to create a new `Image` instance in order to perform rescaling. The API allows you to view or draw scaled versions of an existing `Image` instance. For example, given

```
Image image = new Image("my/res/flower.png");
```

you can create an `ImageView` that displays a scaled version with

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
imageView.setFitWidth(100);
imageView.setFitHeight(150);
```

or you can draw a scaled version to a canvas with

```
Canvas canvas = ... ;
GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
gc.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 0, 0, 100, 150);
```

Answer (score 0):

A late response, but since I ran into the same issue (I needed an Image to pass to setDragView() ), here is the solution I have implemented:

```
Image makeThumbnail(Image original) {
    ImageView i = new ImageView(original);
    i.setFitHeight(64); i.setFitWidth(64);

    return i.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), new WritableImage(64, 64));
}
```